# How to find nearest stations and other POI's to a geo point?

Tags: json, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, google-places-api

I'd like to know how I could get a list of the nearest stations and/or any other nearest POI's (e.g schools) to a specific address or geo point (lat,long).

I've been looking at various examples on google places api and on here but can't find a definitive answer.

I was thinking that I could pass a query to the places api then use the JSON output to list the various POI's?

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

http://f0c9f4b89422f4157058-8258406eeaab1940e57b41fcf78dabca.r6.cf3.rackcdn.com/Ember.png

A lot of sites seem to have this feature so I'm keen to try and replicate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something like [this](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php)

Comment: @davidstrachan That looks perfect, do you collect the station data directly from google and then process or have you got the database on mysql and then process it server side?

Comment: I have a mysql database of uk railway stations and query it for nearest station to user

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the Foursquare API as well - specifically the venues/search capabilities. It was very easy to implement. See the docs here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search

You can pass in the latitude and longitude of the location (or the city/state) and define the radius around which you would like to search. You can also include categories to filter the result set - including transit-related stations (see here for a list of categories: https://developer.foursquare.com/categorytree).

Comment: Not the answer but almost as good, been playing around with it and looks very useful, thanks!

Comment: No problem! I can't comment on Questions just yet (not enough reputation points), which is why I just posted it as an Answer.